# How to prevent 'chpasswd' linux command by time or days with pam?

Tags: linux, security, password, pam

I have Ubuntu 18 OS and I am trying to prevent all users from running 'chpasswd' command after 17:00 o'clock. I need to use pam for this.

My **/etc/pam.d/chpasswd** file:

```
# The PAM configuration file for the Shadow 'chpasswd' service
#

@include common-password

password required       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
account required pam_time.so
```

My **/etc/security/time.conf** file:

```
chpasswd;*;myUser;!Al1700-2400
```

I don't know why it does not work. I can run this command all day.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent that users will be able to run `chpasswd` using `pam_time.so`, as this only ensures that the PAM permission check will fail when a user actually tries to change his or her password.

If your goal is to prevent users from changing their password using `chpasswd` during the specified hours in `/etc/security/time.conf` this approach should suffice.

If you want to prevent users from running `chpasswd` you would need to add something like this cronjob (e.g.`/etc/cron.d/disable_chpasswd`) that disables the permissions for other users to run this program at the specified hour.

```
# disable chpasswd daily at 5pm
0 17 * * * root /usr/bin/chmod 4750 /usr/bin/chpasswd
# enable  chpasswd daily at 5am
0  5 * * * root /usr/bin/chmod 4755 /usr/bin/chpasswd
```

However, if you want to prevent users from changing their password altogether you can't rely on `pam_time.so` (or such a cronjob) because users would still be able to change their password using `passwd` (which as far as I know does not use the *account* management group) or possibly other methods (e.g. some graphical tools use the D-Bus interface provided by AccountsService). To circumvent that you could for example set up a cron job that disables and enables password changing in your PAM configuration (but I don't know if this would be a viable solution for you).